# Hide Quick Launch in SharePoint Masterpage

Tags: 2013, master-page, quick-launch, hide-elements

I want hide master page quick launch from SharePoint 2013.

Comment: did you want to hide just the quick launch or entire left nav? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If it is the SharePoint master page you are using then

Goto site setting (_layouts/15/settings.aspx)

Select the treeview from the look and feel (_layouts/15/navoptions.aspx)

And uncheck the enable quick launch.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with javascript:

```
document.getElementById("sideNavBox").style.display = "none";
```

Or jQuery:

```
$("#sideNavBox").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **add following CSS to masterpage to hide quick launch**:

```
/* hide left navigation */
#sideNavBox{
  display: none !important;
}

/* set contentbox to left */
#contentBox{
  margin-left: 20px !important;
}
```

OR you can remove the `#sideNavBox` using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#sideNavBox").remove();
});
```